# Can Solr Index ASPX Files?

Tags: solr

When I try to index ASPX files using Solr, I keep getting an error. My ASPX file is very standard. Does anyone know if Solr just isn't able to index ASPX files? If I change the extension from ASPX to HTML, Solr can index the file just fine which I find very odd.

The command I use is (im a Windows user):

```
java -Dc=collection -Drecursive -Dfiletypes=aspx jar example/exampledocs/post.jar c:/folder
```

I get the errors:

```
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">400</int>
  <int name="QTime">1</int>
</lst>
<lst name="error">
  <lst name="metadata">
    <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
    <str name="root-error-class">com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException</str>
  </lst>
  <str name="msg">Unexpected character '=' (code 61); expected a semi-colon after the reference for entity 'l'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [8,43]</str>
  <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
</response>
```

In the Solr log:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unexpected character '=' (code 61); expected a semi-colon after the reference for entity 'l'
```

Comment: The `aspx` file being submitted isn't detected as "ASPX", which is a format that Tika doesn't have any relationship to as far as I know. Instead it's attempting to parse the file as XML or something similar, where the reference can't be found. Attempt to set an explicit content type, such as `text/html` or `text/plain` instead. You can do that by setting `-Dtype=text/html`.